# How to use 'AND' in an Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning and I am stuck in this exercise. I just don't understand why the results vary and which way is correct.

I have these tables with their attributes:

> departamentos: codigo, nombre
>
> empleados: codigo, nombre, hijos, retencion, cuenta, fnacimiento
>
> just_nominas: mes, ejercicio, ingreso, descuento, cod_emp
>
> lineas: numero, cantidad, base, porcentaje, mes, ejercicio, cod_emp
>
> trabajan: cod_emp, cod_dep, funcion

English :

Table ***"departments"***:

Attributes:

**Code:** represents the unique code of the department.
**Name:** indicates the name of the department.

> This table stores the information about the departments present in the
> organization

Table ***"employees"***:

**Attributes:**

**Code:** represents the unique code of the employee.

**Name:** indicates the name of the employee.

**Children:** specifies the number of children the employee has.

**Withholding:** indicates the withholding applied to the employee's salary.

**Account:** represents the employee's bank account number.

**Fnacimiento:** indicates the date of birth of the employee.

> This table contains the information of the employees, such as their
> personal data, financial information, and other relevant details.

Table ***"just_payroll"***:

**Attributes:**

**Month:** indicates the month to which the payroll corresponds.

**Fiscal year:** represents the year or fiscal year to which the payroll corresponds.

**Income:** specifies the income in the payroll.

**Discount:** indicates the discount applied to the payroll.

**Cod_emp:** represents the code of the employee to whom the payroll belongs.

> This table stores payslip data, including revenue, deductions, and the
> association with the corresponding employees.

Table ***"lines"***:

**Attributes:**

**Number:** represents the line number.

**Quantity:** indicates the quantity associated with the line.

**Base:** specifies the calculation base.

**Percentage:** indicates the percentage applied.

**Month:** indicates the month to which the line corresponds.

**Year:** represents the year or fiscal year to which the line corresponds.

**Cod_emp:** represents the code of the employee to whom the line belongs.

> This table stores detailed information about the lines associated with
> the payslips, including details such as the amount, the calculation
> base, and the applied percentage.

Table ***"work"***:

**Attributes:**

**Cod_emp:** represents the employee's code.

**Cod_dep:** represents the code of the department.

**Function:** indicates the function or role that the employee performs in the department.

> This table establishes the relationship between employees and
> departments, indicating which employees work in which departments and
> perform which functions.
>
> These tables together allow the storage and relationship of data
> related to departments, employees, payslips, and the associated lines.

The question tells us like this: Employee name and total income earned grouped by name

I have tried to do the query like this:

```sql
SELECT NOMBRE,
       SUM(CANTIDAD)
FROM   EMPLEADOS A
       JOIN JUST_NOMINAS B ON (A.CODIGO=B.COD_EMP)
       JOIN LINEAS C ON (B.COD_EMP=C.COD_EMP)
GROUP BY NOMBRE;
```

But a colleague has told me that it is not like that and that it is like this:

```sql
SELECT E.NOMBRE,
       SUM(L.CANTIDAD) AS INGRESOS_TOTALES
FROM   EMPLEADOS E
       JOIN JUST_NOMINAS J ON E.CODIGO = J.COD_EMP
       JOIN LINEAS L ON J.MES = L.MES
                     AND J.EJERCICIO = L.EJERCICIO
                     AND J.COD_EMP = L.COD_EMP
GROUP BY E.NOMBRE;
```

The result changes a lot, for example, employee 1 gives me: 16000

And to him, the result is 4000

I would like to understand if it is necessary to use those "AND" and why.

**script to test:**

```
 CREATE TABLE empleados (
        codigo      NUMBER(5,0),
        nombre      VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
        hijos       NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
        retencion   NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
        cuenta      CHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        PRIMARY KEY (codigo));
    CREATE TABLE departamentos (
        codigo      NUMBER(5,0),
        nombre      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        PRIMARY KEY (codigo));
    CREATE TABLE trabajan (
        cod_emp     NUMBER(5,0),
        cod_dep     NUMBER(5,0),
        funcion     VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (cod_emp, cod_dep),
        FOREIGN KEY (cod_emp) REFERENCES empleados(codigo),
        FOREIGN KEY (cod_dep) REFERENCES departamentos(codigo));
    CREATE TABLE just_nominas (
        mes     NUMBER(2,0),
        ejercicio   NUMBER(4,0),
        ingreso     NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL,
        descuento   NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL,
        cod_emp     NUMBER(5,0),
        PRIMARY KEY (mes, ejercicio, cod_emp),
        FOREIGN KEY (cod_emp) REFERENCES empleados(codigo));
    CREATE TABLE lineas (
        numero      NUMBER(5,0),
        cantidad    NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL,
        base        NUMBER(8,0),
        porcentaje  NUMBER(2,0),
        mes     NUMBER(2,0),
        ejercicio   NUMBER(4,0),
        cod_emp     NUMBER(5,0),
        PRIMARY KEY (numero, mes, ejercicio, cod_emp),
        FOREIGN KEY (mes, ejercicio, cod_emp) REFERENCES just_nominas(mes, ejercicio, cod_emp));
    
   
   //empleados
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (00011, 'Juan Ignacio Martinez', 0, 10, '12341234121234567890');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (00001, 'José Luis Pérez', 2, 12, '12342233121122334455');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (02341, 'Fernando Romero Díaz', 1, 8, '21341234560987654321');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (11223, 'Manuel Lopez Marín', 0, 10, '55443322110099887766');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (67890, 'Alfonso Gutierrez Lopez', 1, 12, '12563478001234567890');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (00111, 'Encarna Lopez Lopez', 0, 10, '99118822773344665500');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (02031, 'Ines Montero Zafra', 1, 8, '42341534129234567890');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (09876, 'Rosa Lorite Lopez', 0, 10, '52341234521214567890');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (96352, 'Lola Martinez Contreras', 1, 11, '22341224121224567820');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (76543, 'Francisca Colate Gonzalez', 3, 7, '12343234121334567893');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (73152, 'María Pascual Rojo', 3, 7, '12351234151234567590');
    INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (64738, 'Andrés Morales Martín', 3, 7, '22341154116231563690');
    
    //departamentos
    INSERT INTO departamentos VALUES (00001, 'Ventas');
    INSERT INTO departamentos VALUES (00002, 'Compras');
    INSERT INTO departamentos VALUES (00003, 'Marketing');
    INSERT INTO departamentos VALUES (00004, 'Recursos Humanos');
    INSERT INTO departamentos VALUES (00005, 'Administración');
    INSERT INTO departamentos VALUES (00006, 'Dirección');
    
    //trabajan
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (00001, 00001, 'Vendedor');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (00001, 00003, 'Diseñador');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (02341, 00005, 'Administrativo');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (11223, 00006, 'Asesor Dirección');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (11223, 00005, 'Administrativo');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (11223, 00004, 'Selección de Personal');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (67890, 00002, 'Gestor de compras');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (00111, 00001, 'Vendedor');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (02031, 00001, 'Vendedor');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (09876, 00006, 'Director');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (96352, 00003, 'Publicista');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (96352, 00004, 'Encuestador');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (96352, 00005, 'Secretaria de Dirección');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (76543, 00001, 'Vendedor');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (73152, 00005, 'Administrativo');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (73152, 00003, 'Publicista');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (64738, 00001, 'Vendedor');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (64738, 00004, 'Selección de Personal');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (64738, 00002, 'Gestor de compras');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (64738, 00003, 'Diseñador');
    INSERT INTO trabajan VALUES (00011, 00003, 'Diseñador');
    
    //justificantes de nóminas
    
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1200, 200, 00001);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1200, 200, 00001);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1200, 200, 00001);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1200, 200, 00001);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1500, 300, 02341);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1500, 300, 02341);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1500, 300, 02341);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1500, 300, 02341);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1000, 100, 11223);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1000, 100, 11223);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1000, 100, 11223);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1000, 100, 11223);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1200, 200, 67890);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1200, 200, 67890);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1200, 200, 67890);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1200, 200, 67890);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1200, 200, 00111);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1200, 200, 00111);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1200, 200, 00111);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1200, 200, 00111);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1200, 200, 02031);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1200, 200, 02031);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1200, 200, 02031);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1200, 200, 02031);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1200, 200, 09876);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1200, 200, 09876);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1200, 200, 09876);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1200, 200, 09876);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1200, 200, 96352);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1200, 200, 96352);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1200, 200, 96352);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1200, 200, 96352);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1200, 200, 76543);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1200, 200, 76543);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1200, 200, 76543);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1200, 200, 76543);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1200, 200, 73152);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1200, 200, 73152);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1200, 200, 73152);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1200, 200, 73152);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (10, 2006, 1200, 200, 64738);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (11, 2006, 1200, 200, 64738);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (12, 2006, 1200, 200, 64738);
    INSERT INTO just_nominas VALUES (01, 2007, 1200, 200, 64738);
    
    //lineas
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 00001);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 00001);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 00001);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 00001);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 00001);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 00001);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 00001);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 00001);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1500, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 02341);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -300, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 02341);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1500, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 02341);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -300, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 02341);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1500, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 02341);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -300, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 02341);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1500, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 02341);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -300, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 02341);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1000, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 11223);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -100, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 11223);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1000, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 11223);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -100, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 11223);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1000, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 11223);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -100, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 11223);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1000, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 11223);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -100, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 11223);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 67890);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 67890);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 67890);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 67890);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 67890);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 67890);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 67890);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 67890);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 00111);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 00111);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 00111);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 00111);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 00111);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 00111);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 00111);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 00111);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 02031);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 02031);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 02031);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 02031);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 02031);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 02031);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 02031);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 02031);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 09876);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 09876);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 09876);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 09876);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 09876);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 09876);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 09876);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 09876);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 96352);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 96352);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 96352);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 96352);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 96352);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 96352);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 96352);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 96352);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 76543);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 76543);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 76543);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 76543);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 76543);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 76543);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 76543);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 76543);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 73152);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 73152);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 73152);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 73152);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 73152);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 73152);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 73152);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 73152);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 10, 2006, 64738);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 10, 2006, 64738);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 11, 2006, 64738);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 11, 2006, 64738);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 12, 2006, 64738);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 12, 2006, 64738);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00001, 1200, NULL, NULL, 01, 2007, 64738);
    INSERT INTO lineas VALUES (00002, -200, 1200, 10, 01, 2007, 64738);
    
    ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY';
    ALTER TABLE empleados ADD fnacimiento DATE;
    
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('01/02/1960', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 00011;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('12/04/1964', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 00001;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('25/09/1955', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 02341;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('13/12/1963', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 11223;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('05/11/1967', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 67890;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('15/03/1968', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 00111;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('22/02/1972', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 02031;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('18/08/1975', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 09876;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('09/03/1975', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 96352;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('02/03/1969', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 76543;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('09/12/1973', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 73152;
    UPDATE empleados SET fnacimiento = TO_DATE('20/01/1964', 'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE codigo = 64738;
    
    COMMIT;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables with the primary and foreign key constraints so we know how the tables are related; and an explanation of what the columns mean and translate them into English (removing any that are irrelevant to the question); include `INSERT` statements for some sample data. At the moment, the question is impossible to answer as we don't know what your table represent and it is not clear which version would be correct.

Comment: In addition to @MT0, please refrain from using language other than English when you write code. This makes it extremely hard for people to help you. Not all of us know Spanish. Furthermore, it will waste you time when you need help, because you will need to translate everything in English to ask your question. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new, I'll try to do what you ask

Comment: I understand it and I am very sorry that the tables are in Spanish, unfortunately the script that the teacher gave us is like this.
But I understand that being another language makes it difficult to understand.
I really like the English forum, since they have helped me a lot, so next time I will try to put everything in English before consulting

Comment: Done ^^ y up script to test and traslate

Answer (score 0):

You are only using 3 tables in your queries. Running them through an online translator translates:

```
empleados: codigo, nombre
just_nominas: mes, ejercicio, ingreso, descuento, cod_emp
lineas: numero, cantidad, base, porcentaje, mes, ejercicio, cod_emp
```

to:

```
employees: code, name
just_payroll: month, year, income, discount, cod_emp
lines: number, quantity, base, percentage, month, year, cod_emp
```

It is unclear that "lines" would have anything to do with income and so you may only need two tables:

```sql
SELECT name,
       SUM(income)
FROM   employees e
       INNER JOIN just_payroll p
       ON e.code = p.cod_emp
GROUP BY
       e.name;
```

---

Your code:

> ```sql
> SELECT NOMBRE,
>        SUM(CANTIDAD)
> FROM   EMPLEADOS A
>        JOIN JUST_NOMINAS B ON (A.CODIGO=B.COD_EMP)
>        JOIN LINEAS C ON (B.COD_EMP=C.COD_EMP)
> GROUP BY NOMBRE;
> ```

Is not correct.

There is a composite foreign key constraint between the line and payroll tables on three columns `month`, `year` and `cod_emp` and you are only joining the table on one column `cod_emp`

This means that, for the first employee, you join the `payroll` row from 2006-10 to the `line` rows in 2006-10, 2006-11, 2006-12 and 2007-01 (because you only match on the employee number and not on the month and year) and, similarly, the other `payroll` rows for that employee are also joined to all four `line` rows so you are getting four times the number of rows and is why your total is quadruple your colleagues.

---

That does not mean that your colleague's code is correct either; as already mentioned, there does not appear to be any need to use the `line` table and can just use the `employees` and `payroll` tables to get the total of the `income` column.

If you want to get the total with the discounts (which does not appear to be what the question is asking) then, yes, your colleague's code may be correct. (Although the `line` data is slightly strange as when `base` is 1200 and the `percentage` is 10 then the `discount` column is `-200`, which is 16.7% and not 10%.)

Comment: I have shared the script that I used to create the tables with your data, maybe it can help you understand me better.

I also made a small explanation of what each table is in English